# How to create web form in SharePoint which has two lists combined or which can achieve master and transaction data capture

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, custom-list, custom-form, list-form

I am very Beginner in SharePoint and i have assignment as below
I want to capture below form in SharePoint /which has tentatively below mentioned fields, I am facing difficulties in capturing point no 4 data and linking this master and transaction records.
this form should support all CRUD operations with access rights and should keep history. once this data is collected a pdf report to be generated as below.

1. Accident no: **< Auto Generated >** (YYYY0000)  *(How to achieve this)*
2. Accident Date: < DDMMYYYY >     Accident Time: <HH:MM> (Auto)
3. Type of Accident: < Drop down > <First Aid / Medical case/ Fatal/ Fire/ Near Miss/ Property Damage……….)
4. Details of the injured:   *(How to achieve this)*

| Sr | Name(Text) | Age (number) | Company name | Employee Mob no |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------ |
| 2 | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------ |
| 3 | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------ |

6. Incident Major Location: < Dropdown > (list area Name)
7. Other Equipment's involved:< Dropdown - editable  > (Optional)

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you working with?

Comment: sharepoint online

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box forms won't allow you to do this. You have two main options:

- Low code: Use Power Apps
- Code: write your own application, using for example the SharePoint Framework.

Instead of SharePoint, you might also want to take a look at Dataverse or Dataverse for Teams, which is more akin to a database.